# ITK and VTK Wrapping into Python using Cmake

Tags: python, cmake, vtk, itk

can we wrap all ITK and VTK files into Python by using cmake? I need full functionalities and all header files to be imported into python.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is Python wrapping available for ITK and VTK. To install the wrapping,

`python -m pip install --upgrade pip
python -m pip install itk vtk`

For more information on the ITK Python wrapping and how it automatically exposes the full functionality of the header files, see the [Wrapping](https://itk.org/ITKSoftwareGuide/html/Book1/ITKSoftwareGuide-Book1ch3.html#x39-440003.7) section of the ITK Software Guide.

To add your own Python wrapping for new ITK classes, see the section on [ITK Modules](https://itk.org/ITKSoftwareGuide/html/Book1/ITKSoftwareGuide-Book1ch9.html#x55-1490009) and the [ITK Module Template](https://github.com/InsightSoftwareConsortium/ITKModuleTemplate).